# AsyncTask with ResponseListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I would like to get data from JSON and doing this in the asyncTask. The problem is that the onPostExecute is executed before the doInBackground.

So here is my fragment where I called the execute :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new GetPlantsList().execute();


}
```

And my AsyncTask

```
public class GetPlantsList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Si pas d'erreur
                try {
                    // Here my JSON response

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        //On récupére le fichier php via la variable dans strings.xml et on envoi la requete
        PlantsListRequest plantsListRequest = new PlantsListRequest(user_id, responseListener, getResources().getString(R.string.php_file) + "get_plants_list.php");
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(plantsListRequest);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // Initialisation de la recycler view (qui va comporter la liste des plantes)
        rv_plants = (RecyclerView) view_frag.findViewById(R.id.rv_list_plants);

        //On vient créer la liste des plantes avec la class Recycler view Plants List (on lui envoie toutes les plantes de mon utilisateurs)
        PlantsList plantsList = new PlantsList(getActivity(), tv_plants_name, tv_plants_variety, iv_plants_img, id_plants);

        //Mon recycler view vient afficher la liste des plantes
        rv_plants.setAdapter(plantsList);
        rv_plants.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

}
```

In my onPostExecute, I just try to display all the informations that I got from the JSON (and to do this at the end of the request ;)).

I m new in the android programmation. Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: how do you know that postexecute execute before doinbackground?
set adapter can be in oncreate, what the point to put it onpost? what are epecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the `onPostExecute` is executed before the `doInBackground`.

`RequestQueue` in `Volley` that operates ***asynchronously*** through network threads. thus, `onPostExecute` is called before the response of `plantsListRequest` in `doInBackground`.

If you want to block thread(task) while network call, you can use `RequestFuture`. ***But, it's not recommended.*** you could simply implement network calls via `NetworkQueue` with `Listener`. (without `AsyncTask`).

### Using RequestFuture

```java
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    
    //On récupére le fichier php via la variable dans strings.xml et on envoi la requete
    PlantsListRequest plantsListRequest = new PlantsListRequest(user_id, future, getResources().getString(R.string.php_file) + "get_plants_list.php");
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    queue.add(plantsListRequest);

    String response = future.get(); // blocking thread

    return null;
}
```

### Volley

[image: volley - request]

#### Reference

- https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple